# How i can animate navigation drawer resize itself to half screen?

Tags: android

the whole navigation bar comes front and the main activity shifts towards left and gets shrink. Please anyone can tell me the easiest way to do this??

Comment: what did you tried so far show your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp" <!-- Set the width -->
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        #Your view

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: 1. Don't answer questions that put in no effort because it encourages new users to continue posting bad content. 2. Code only answers aren't great because it doesn't explain what you're doing. We want to teach,  not just let people copy/paste